# How to combine angular-translate and angular-dynamic-locale on select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-translate

I want to change my translation and my locale together on the same html select.
At this point I have two locales and languages: `de_DE` and `en_US`.

How can I combine these two angular modules ([angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale))?

Here are working plunkers for both modules:

[angular-translate plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pjYRHL5Nexu6lAThPZf3?p=preview)

[angular-dynamic-locale plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lVQQTtltumaRjWZnWfQh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution here:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/internationalization-of-angularjs-applications

Demo: https://blog.gospodarets.com/angular-translate-yeoman/dist/#/

Github repository: https://github.com/malyw/angular-translate-yeoman